# UITableViewCell background spanning multiple cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

This is end end result I want:

[image]

And this is the thing I tried initially.

[image]

This does not work, the cells below/above the cell with the background will overlap or underlap the background depending on when they are added into the tableview (like via dequeue/scrolling).

I am quite OK with this not working, and I believe I can achieve it by other means. For example by adding these backgrounds as views within the tableview itself and moving them based on the content offset or similar ways, maybe adding a background image that is tall with them embedded.

But. I am curious if there are some easier way, just adding the view into the XIB and applying a rotation would be very nice.

The background should be below the text in the other cells as well - this is where the complications comes in.

Anyway. Is this possible in some super-neat way?

Comment: np. Do you still have the problem if the cell backgrounds of the other cells are set to be clear?

Comment: Yes, because the cell with the background will still overlap the above/below cell if those are added before the cell with the background. For those added after, it looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is setting all cell's background to clear, and to set a background to your `UITableView` or your `UIView`. 
Or, as you suggest, you can add a UIView with a rotation applied, and add it as a subview of your `UIView`/`UITableView`, and send it to back with `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView]`.

Comment: I mentioned this above, but I'll do it again. The 'clear' thing will not really work. Because if we - e.g. scroll downwards - the cell below the one with bg will be added at "index 0". Then the cell with bg is added at "1". At this point the bg'd cell will be on a higher z-index (the bg itself is z-indexed within the cell) and be displayed above. The next cell though, with index "2" will be added on top again, and this cell is displayed correctly.

Comment: If you add your background to `UITableView` and not to `UITableViewCell`, this problem should not appear. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Correct, I am merely entertaining the idea of doing it per-cell basis now because it would be nicer.

The issue with adding it into the tableview itself is that I don't know where it will need backgrounds, how long it will be or how many I will need. So it would have to be generated / manually done. But yeah, it looks like I have to go some way like that.

Comment: Do you want the background to be moving as the `UITableView` is scrolling, or to be fixed ?

Comment: It should be scrolling. In the example images you see that the grey background is behind a little image (map, in the example). The background would follow this image when scrolling. 

It is purely visual candy.

Comment: And if you just do the following : you say that in your last image, the background is overlapping depending on when the UITableViewCell is added. If you call `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundView]` (or something like that) in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` maybe it will solve your issue ?

Comment: I just tried it (also found another SO q. that mentioned something like this - trying to send the cell/view inside to the bottom (tableview sendSubv..)). It didn't work and I also noticed that if a cell is dequeued it will pop away anyway, so the overlapping backgrounds would just disappear instantly. Kinda of ugly.

I also saw a mention that UICollectionView have zOrdering natively so that might be a solution.

For now I think I will skip it but I will update with some answer when I finish it. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: I have a couple of solutions (not a solution to the exact question) but I'll probably do a write up and post it as an answer when I pick one way to do it.

Comment: @JonathanWinger-Lang did you end up writing this up?

Comment: @zaitsman I did not, unfortunately. I think I went with a single cell with text+image+text (and the background) but I don't really even remember right now.